# Jmeter how to define test users to execute different transaction in the same thread group

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

I would like to test behavior of the system for 50 users. 25 users have to do action X, with input A and 25 users have to do action Y, with input B (Users X and Y are in the CSV file). I want the top 25 users in the CSV file to do action X and the bottom 25 to do action Y.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is just adding an extra column called "action" to the CSV file so you will be able to assign the associated action to each user.

---

If for some reason you cannot amend the CSV file you can use a [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) with the following _[_groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) as the condition:

```
${__groovy((new File('your_file.csv').readLines().indexOf(vars.get('your_variable_from_csv_holding_the_username')) < 25) ? 'A' : 'B',)}
```

And add 2 [Simple Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller) named `A` and `B` as children of the Switch Controller. The "actions" are to be added to the Simple Controllers.

Small demo with the following CSV file:

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
user5
user6
user7
user8
user9
user10
```

[image]